# WPF ListView dynamically added columns are not visible

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I have a problem with WPF Listview when dynamically adding and removing the GridViewColumns.
If i remove some columns from ListView, then later adding the removed columns, the added columns are not visible !!

I am removing the columns like this.

```
     List<GridViewColumn> gvLists;

     for (int i = 0; i < grdView.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            // keeping the grdView cols in to a list for later adding back
            gvLists.Add(grdView.Columns[i]);
        }

        // here removing the columns from ListView.GridView
        foreach (GridViewColumn g in gvLists)
        {
            if (g.Header.ToString() != "ID")
            {
                grdView.Columns.Remove(g);
            }
        }
```

And adding back those cols later like this

```
    foreach (GridViewColumn g in gvLists)
    {
       if(!grdView.Columns.Contains(g))  grdView.Columns.Add(g);
    }
```

But these added columns are not visible in the ListView. But if debugg and check the columns, all the added columns are there. Why the added columns are not visible ?

After I added these columns, I tried to call InvalidateMeasure and Arrange. But no use.

Also I noticed one more thing is that, the ListView Loaded event is firing several times!!

I am binding the ListView with a DataTable from a DataSet and not using MVVM.

And one more thing is that, I used HeaderTemplates for all the columns as shown below :

```
 <GridViewColumn Width="50" Header="Name">
     <GridViewColumn.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
           <DockPanel>
             <TextBlock Height="23" TextAlignment="Center" Text="Name" Width="80"/>
             <Path Name="SortArrow" StrokeThickness="1" Fill="Gray" Data="M 5,5 L 10,10 L 15,5 L 5,5" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
           </DockPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
     </GridViewColumn.HeaderTemplate>
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
           <TextBox Text="{Binding Name.....}" Width="20" Height="15" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

The column removing and adding back is triggered by the check value of a check box in the window. If I check that check box, i will call RemoveCols(), and calling AddCols() when uncheck it.

Comment: are the columns you are adding text columns?

Comment: yes. Every column have a header template and a cell template defined. If a column's header template contains textbox, then its cell template has a textbox. If the a column's header template contains a combobox, then its cell template has a combo box.

Comment: `I am binding the ListView with a DataTable from a DataSet and not using MVVM.` - you're wasting your time by trying to force WPF to a winforms approach. You will fail. WPF does not support developers with a winforms mentality. Create 2 separate ListViews in 2 separate UserControls and use a ContentPresenter to switch between these when you checkbox is checked. You don't really need to add columns in procedural code to a ListView.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not authorised to use MVVM

Comment: @James not "authorized"?? what in the world does that mean? sorry, but that is ridiculous.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
foreach (GridViewColumn g in gvLists)
        {
            if (!grdView.Columns.Contains(g))
            {
                g = new GridViewColumn();
                grdView.Columns.Add(g);
            }
        }
```

Comment: cannot use g = new GridViewColumn() because g is in foreach iteration.